# Exposing an ISO C++ class to a VB6 application

Tags: c++, class, com, vb6

I have developed a C++ class to access the software protection dongle on USB. The C++ class has been developed with g++ under Linux, but I can compile it successfully using MinGW under Windows. I have a scientific application which is built with VB6 (Visual Basic 6).

The question is how can I expose my C++ class to a VB6 app? What are the possible ways to do it? Do I need to use COM? (Well, a "Microsoft-less" solution is more preferable:)

Your help is much appreciated!

**Update 1.** Reading your comments I realized I need to implement a COM wrapper to the C++ class. Are there any good and recent examples around? Can I implement the COM wrapper using MinGW (and avoiding MSVC)?

**Update 2.** Finally, I decided to offer a bounty for this question. Below are the things I would like to understand better:

**1.** I realized I need to implement a COM wrapper to my C++ class. Can someone please provide me with working example on how to make this for a class like this:

```
class ValueMapper
{
public:
    ValueMapper( ) { }

    ValueMapper( double fmin, double fmax, int ilength ) {
        SetMapping( fmin, fmax, ilength );
    }

    inline double GetMin() { return min; }
    inline double GetMax() { return max; }
    inline int GetLength() { return length; }

    virtual inline void SetMapping( double fmin, double fmax, int ilength )
    {
        min = fmin;
        max = fmax;
        length = ilength;
    }

    virtual inline int MapValue( double value ) {
        double factor = length / (max - min);
        return (int)RoundTo( (value-min) * factor );
    }

    static double RoundTo( double value, double eps = 1 ) {
        return floor(value/eps + 0.5) * eps;
    }

protected:
    double  min;
    double  max;
    int     length;
};
```

**2.** How to use the resulting COM wrapper from the VB6? Do I need to register a COM server or so? Can I use it without registering?

**3.** Optional. Is it possible to implement a COM wrapper using MinGW?

Comment: lots of possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vb6+call+c%2B%2B

Comment: [Notes for Developing DLLs for use with Visual Basic](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp)

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid COM? VB 6 is fully entrenched in COM development. It's difficult to imagine what you accomplish in trying to use a "Microsoft-less" solution. If you wanted that, you wouldn't be writing a VB 6 application or running it on Windows.

Comment: @Cody Gray, thanks for the link to **the notes**! It really worths reading. Well, It seems like I need to use COM. Are there any recent examples of a COM wrappers to ISO C++ classes?

Comment: You don't *have* to use COM. There are other ways of doing this, but doing it via COM is actually simpler. That's a bit ironic, as there's historically been nothing "simple" about COM, but that's what VB 6 is based on, and once you get past the initial hurdles of COM development, it does greatly simplify interop scenarios like this. I can't really give you any advice on MinGW; I don't much care for it and have never really used it for serious Windows development.

Comment: about point 2: vb6 .exe(s) silently registres all missing and accesible (same directory or elsewhere) COM componets at runtime

Answer (score 8):

To make access to a COM C++ class from Visual Basic you will need to specify its interface in the meta-language known as IDL. It will be used to generate type library that will be read by Visual Basic and class skeleton in C++ to be implemented like i.e. delegating calls to a ValueMapper object. It is done by the tool called midl.exe. It comes with Windows Platform SDK or any VC++ environment. If you do not own one you can download it along with VC++ 10 Express Edition for free.

The IDL file for you object could look like:

```
import "oaidl.idl"; 
[
 uuid(C6907FD4-9F56-499A-A784-6168AB3352D6),
 version(1.0),
 local,
 oleautomation
]
interface IValueMapper : IDispatch
{
  [id(1), propget] double Min();
  [id(2),propget] double Max();
  [id(3),propget] int Length();
  [id(4)] void SetMapping( [in] double fmin, [in] double fmax, [in] int ilength );
  [id(5)] int MapValue([in] double value);
  [id(6)] double RoundTo( [in] double value,[in,defaultvalue(1)] double eps );
};

[
  uuid(1C110E43-A56F-41A2-8052-EF85FF96082F),
  version(1.0),
  helpstring("Value Mapper Library"),
] library ValueMapperLib
{
  importlib("stdole32.tlb");
  interface IValueMapper;
  [
  uuid(D1A2F830-994E-4495-A9C3-1440155578A9),
  helpstring("Value Mapper Component Class")
  ] 
  coclass ValueMapperClassObject
  {
    [default] interface IValueMapper;
  }; //end coclass def
};
```

Now you can provide the required functionality by deriving a class from IValueMapper and implement its functionality by using a ValueMapper member. Unfortunately you will also need to provide some boilerplate code to implement the class object, and IUnknown and IDispatch interfaces as well as the DLL registration code. You can find relevant code snippets on the Internet i.e., on the pages like:

http://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/LV/Components04/VL5/MSDN/DrGUI-on-COM.html
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/simplecomserver.aspx

Also I have assembled a VC++ 10 complete project that implements this interface so let me know if you would like to take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there way to make an IDL file out of a C++ class header? Do I always need to provide a .tlb file in order to use the resulting COM object DLL in VB6 project?

Comment: As IDL contains more information than class header like marking in,out parameters it is usually not possible to generate it out of a standard class header. The .tlb library is required by VB to learn about the class interface but it is generated automatically by the midl compiler and read by VB. So you do not need to worry about it.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it. So I need to (1) create an IDL file with description of an interface, (2) generate a C++ header using midl.exe utility, (3) implement the corresponding COM object, (4) compile it into a DLL file, (5) generate a .tlb file out of IDL to use my COM object in VB6 application, (6) import the .tlb into a VB6 project. Right?

Comment: Another two questions: Are there any free editors that support IDL programming (or maybe just IDL syntax highlighting)? Is it possible to specify an array of custom types (structs) as an input / output parameter in IDL and use it in VB6?

Comment: Yes, for convenience you may put the .tlb lib inside the dll using a resources file (.rc) in the VC++ project and register both at the same time. Look at the second link I posted which comes with an example project that contains some generic code that may be reused.

Comment: For editing IDL I would recommend any Visual C++ like the free VC++ 10 Express Edition, you can add idl to the project and it will be recognized and automatically compiled. So there is no need to manually touch midl.exe. Maybe VB will recognize it too. A stand alone editor that recognises IDL I am aware of is Crimson Editor but most will do as well I think.

Comment: Do I really need to inherit from IDispatch instead of IUnknown?

Comment: Yes, this is the interface Visual Basic runtime uses internally to make calls on objects. You can use the boiler plate implementation from examples that use the default Windows handlers.

Comment: Thanks! I finally get it to work with just IUnknown based implementation! But how can I pass a text string parameter?

Comment: COM and VB use the type BSTR for strings.

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible ways I am aware of:

1) Write a COM wrapper around your class and access it directly from VB6.

2) Make a C interface of your class (by "flattening it") and expose it in a plain DLL.

The former approach is more common, but it sounds like you might prefer the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel like it would be less painful to write a COM wrapper?!

Comment: @ezpresso: It really depends on what you are more comfortable with. In fact if you are using MingW, writing a COM component may not be trivial at all.